# Django QuerySet reverse join

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**models.py**

I have two models:

```
class UserProducts(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                      
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='user_id', 
    related_name='user_name')                                                                                                 
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Products', db_column='product_id', 
    related_name='user_products')                                                                                   
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('categories', 
    db_column='category_id', related_name='user_products')                                                                               
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=False, default='')                                                                                                        
    url = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                      
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                    
    price = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                    
    location = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                 
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                 
    quantity_unit = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                            
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                           
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                             
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                    
    is_verified = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                           
    is_organic = models.IntegerField()                                                                                                                                                 
    details = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.                                                                                                          
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)                                                                                                                            
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                           
    image_id = models.ForeignKey('Files', db_column='image_id', 
                  related_name='image_products', blank=True, null=True)                                                                  
    #variety_id = models.ForeignKey(ProductVarieties, 
                   db_column='variety_id', 
                   related_name='product_variety', blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class UserProductVarieties(models.Model):
     user_product = models.ForeignKey('UserProducts', db_constraint=False, related_name='product_variety')
     product_variety = models.ForeignKey('ProductVarieties', db_constraint=False)
     moq = models.IntegerField()
     moq_unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey('User', default=94, related_name='create_product_variety_name')
     updated_by = models.ForeignKey('User', default=94, related_name='update_product_variety_name')
```

I want to nest all the `UserProductVarieties` inside the `UserProduct` queryset.

> I am trying to create a queryset and not just a specific field.

Here are the things I've tried:

1. Using a reverse serializer field. -> only shows the specific field
2. A nested serializer inside UserProductsSerializer -> works with `.create` but not for listing.
3. [.select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) on the queryset. The documentation only shows how to join using `ForeignKeys` in the current table. Whereas I want to join based on `ForeignKeys` in a different table to the current table.

Comment: Is [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) a solution for you like so: `UserProduct.objects.all().prefetch_related('product_variety')`?

Comment: i can get that through `.select_related('product_variety')`, but it only returns me just that field. What I need is entire `product_variety` object to be nested inside the response of `user_product`

Comment: please provide a complete example queryset filtering (like I did)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this,

```
class UserProductVarietiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProductVarieties
        fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields if not 'user_product']

class UserProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product_varieties = UserProductVarietiesSerializer(source='product_variety')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProducts
        additional_fields = ['product_varieties']
        fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields] + additional_fields

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #custom create function
        product_varieties = validated_data.pop('product_variety')
        instance = super(UserProductSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #custom update function
        product_varieties = validated_data.pop('product_variety')
        instance = super(UserProductSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Also, for better performance you amy need to add,

```
UserProduct.objects.prefetch_related('product_variety')
```

in your `views`.

Comment: i already have implemented write functionality, i cannot see a product_varieties field when i do a GET. and in your answer, source kwarg is redundant, django will give an error.

Comment: I've removed `write_only=True` from field in serializer, now it should show them in the GET request. For create/update you may need to tweak the corresponding method accordingly, I've only written the basic layout for the context.

Comment: Did you use the one in answer?

Comment: i have explicitly added all fields in the `fields` tuple, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: change `product_varieties` => `product_variety` in source keyword argument. My mistake, try now.

Comment: I'm getting a new erro -> `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'UserProducts'`. I guess this is some sort of error with the serializer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154989/discussion-between-ishan-khare-and-zaidfazil).

Comment: Would you then tag my answer as selected, then if you don't mind?